# In Jsoup, is it possible get the Elements from a list of Elements without runs through it?

Tags: java, robots.txt, jsoup

I'm new to Jsoup, but this appears to be a great tool. I'm trying to extract the robots metatag.

I have the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
Elements metatags = doc.select("meta");
Element robots = metatags.attr("name", "robots"); // is getting the first element of the list
```

The last line is wrong.

I want to know if is necessary to run the list of elements to find the element that matches the attribute or there a way that extracts the element that matches the attribute from the Elements list.

Edit 1: I solved this changing to `doc.select("meta[name=robots]")`.

Edit 2: In another words: I want to know how to get all elements in a `Elements list` that matches some atribute requisite.

Edit 3: I was precipitated doing this question because I had not seen the main documentation yet. Sorry.

Comment: +1 for "Jsoup, but this appeas to be a great tool."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to set the attribute and value you want to retrieve in the `select()` method to do a better filtering.

Change the select to: `doc.select("meta[name=robots]");` and it will get all elements that has the meta tag and it have the name attribute equals robots.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the JSoup documentation? Here it is from the method you are using:

```
attr

public Elements attr(String attributeKey,
                     String attributeValue)

    Set an attribute on all matched elements.

    Parameters:
        attributeKey - attribute key 
        attributeValue - attribute value 
    Returns:
        this
```

It returns this. Which means it will return an `Elements` object. This can't be assigned to an `Element` object.

I also think you want to use `Document.getElementsByTag(String)`, instead of `select`.